# How to write to visual studio output window

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages

Using asp.net core 2.x razor pages.
While building a handler method, I want to write some text to the output window in visual studio 2017.

I have a breakpoint set on my handler and its hit, but this line of code does not result in anything being written to the output window.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("test");
```

Comment: Looks like that might not work in .net core 2.2-1.0 but fixed in 3.0? https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16596